# why can't use \" in HTML input tag?

Tags: html

i want show `12"3` in my input tag value

i write this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="" value="12\"3">
```

but it's not be right

WHY ?

PS: i must transfer `"` to `&quot;` ,or change `"` to `'`? i don't like it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML simply does not have escape sequences like other languages. In HTML attribute values the only special characters are `<`, `&` and depending on the quotes `"` or `'`. And the only to use these characters are [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3):

> Some authors use the character entity reference "`&quot;`" to encode instances of the double quote mark (`"`) since that character may be used to delimit attribute values.

Or you use single quotes, then you don’t need to encode the double quotes and vice versa:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="" value='12"3'>
```

Comment: but this solution can't type `'` in tag value

Comment: @Zenofo: If you want to use both single and double quotes in the same attribute value, then you need to represent one of these characters with a character reference: `"'&quot;"` or `'"&#39;'`.

Comment: @Zenofo Of course it can, you just need to use the HTML entity `&apos;` or `&#x0027;`.

Comment: @Reinis I.: `&apos;` is not defined in HTML; it was introduced in XML 1.0.

Comment: The only XHTML correct way is to use the entities, `&quot;` and `&apos;`

Comment: @Gumbo that's correct they equate to the same thing. I intended my comment to read... "The only XHTML correct way is to use the entities" ... and provided the symbolic entities for reference.

Comment: @slomojo: But `&#39;` and `&#x0027;` are not entities; they are character references. *apos* and *quot* are entities that can be referenced with the corresponding entity references `&apos;` and `&quot;`.

Comment: @Gumbo, I know, I was just being simplistic.

Answer (score 5):

> WHY ?

Because `\` is not special in HTML. It does not escape stuff. You must use `&quot;` or `'`.

```
 <input type="text" name="somename" value='12"3' />
 <input type="text" name="somename2" value="12&quot;3" />
```