# How to escape JavaScript in JSP?

Tags: javascript, string, jsp, escaping

I'm totally stuck on this, I'm trying to escape a single quote in a JSP. I have some data that I'm outputting directly into a JS string and the single quotes seem to be causing issues.

Here is my code:

```xml
<dsp:droplet name="/atg/dynamo/droplet/ForEach">
  <dsp:param value="${CommerceItems}" name="array" />
  <dsp:param name="elementName" value="CommerceItem" />
  <dsp:oparam name="outputStart">
    var itemNameList ='
  </dsp:oparam>
  <dsp:oparam name="output">
    <dsp:getvalueof id="Desc" param="CommerceItem.auxiliaryData.productRef.displayName">
      ${fn:replace(Desc, "'", "\\/'")}
    </dsp:getvalueof>
  </dsp:oparam>
  <dsp:oparam name="outputEnd">';</dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
```

And here is the output that Im getting:

```js
var itemNameList ='
Weyland Estate Santa Barbara Pinot Noir
Raymond \/'Prodigal\/' North Coast Cabernet Sauvignon
Chateau Haute Tuque';
```

But this is wrong, and I just need `/'Prodigal'/` or no single quotes at all!

---

**EDIT**: Or I actually need to escape quotes with `\` backward slash?

Comment: Looks like its \\'  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470768/how-to-escape-apostrophe-or-quotes-on-a-jsp-used-by-javascript

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The forward slash is not an escape character. That's the backslash.

```
${fn:replace(Desc, "'", "\\'")}
```

*(yes, it's been presented twice, because that's **also** an escape character in Java!)*

However, you don't only need to repace `'` by `\'`, you also need to replace `\n` (newlines) by `\\n`. The string is been printed over multiple lines, which makes it also an invalid JS string variable. Your final result must *basically* look like this:

```js
var itemNameList = ''
    + '\nWeyland Estate Santa Barbara Pinot Noir'
    + '\nRaymond \'Prodigal\' North Coast Cabernet Sauvignon'
    + '\nChateau Haute Tuque';
```

*(please note that the syntax highlighter agrees on me here but not on yours)*

There are however *much* more possible special characters which needs to be escaped. They are all covered by [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeEcmaScript()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String)). Much easier is to create a custom EL function which calls exactly that method. If not done yet, download and drop `commons-lang.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Then create a `/WEB-INF/functions.tld` file like follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <display-name>Custom Functions</display-name>    
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <uri>http://example.com/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>escapeJS</name>
        <function-class>org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

So that you can use it as follows:

```xml
<%@taglib prefix="util" uri="http://example.com/functions" %>
...
${util:escapeJS(Desc)}
```

Comment: Spring has a ready made tag for that: [_s:escapeBody_](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.escapeBody) , so if you are using Spring, you can use it without defining own custom tags.

Comment: OmniFaces also has one: [of:escapeJS](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings)

Comment: s:escapeBody needs to be separate answer @DavidBalažic

Answer (score 0):

Following up on a previous comment ([How to escape JavaScript in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708242/how-to-escape-javascript-in-jsp#comment57900248_9709168)): If you're using Spring MVC, you can use the [escapeBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.8/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/EscapeBodyTag.html) tag in your JSP:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

...

<s:escapeBody>${text}</s:escapeBody>
```