# Pass a GET parameter to a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jsp, methods, parameters, get

I have this code

```
<%=out.write("<input 
  type=\"hidden\" 
  id=\"tid\" 
  value=\""+request.getParameter("id").toString()+"
\"/>")%>
<script type="text/javascript">
  getPage(document.getElementById("tid").value)
</script>
```

This code creates a hidden field with the value came from

`<site root>/viewPage.jsp?id=erwdf`

url and pass the value of this hidden field to a jsp function. When I ran this code on Tomcat it gave an error as

> The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for
>   the arguments (void)

on JSP code line I given above. So am I doing anything wrong or is there any alternative method to pass a GET parameter to a JavaScript function? I don't know much about Javascript just started to learn it.

Comment: Why so overcomplicated with a hidden field? Why not just `getPage('<%=request.getParameter("id")%>')`?

Comment: thanks @BalusC that was amazing. Actually I don't have much experience in JavaScript. Now its giving value as `getPage('adsd');` so are single quoted data are treated as strings in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it's treated as a global variable, but you don't have any JS variable with that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why so overcomplicated with a hidden field?

Just do

```
getPage('<%=request.getParameter("id")%>');
```

Or easier, with EL

```
getPage('${param.id}');
```

You may only want to escape special JS characters by [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) `StringEscapeUtils`, otherwise the generated JS code may break whenever the parameter value contains a single quote or any other special JS character.

```
getPage('<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(request.getParameter("id"))%>');
```

Or when in EL

```
getPage('${util:escapeJS(param.id)}');
```

#### See also:

- [How to escape JavaScript in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708242/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-from-within-a-jsp/9709168#9709168)

Comment: Thanks @BalusC nice one. I will give it a try after understanding the post you linked and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you meant `<%out.write` instead of `<%=out.write`

about the other issue from the comments, this will assist with getPage and perform escaping of quotes, other special chars...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  getPage("<% try {
      out.write(URLEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("id").toString(), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } %>")
</script>
```

Comment: ya it worked thanks @dldnh but again my Javascript function getPage is not executing

Comment: instead of putting the value into an `<input>` and using `document.getElementById` you should just pass it directly to `getPage` -- `getPage("<% out.write(request.getParameter("id").toString()); %>")` -- probably need some escaping, too, inside the quotes

Comment: don't u think it will pass the whole `"<% out.write(request.getParameter("id").toString()); %>"` to getPage()??
I only want to pass the id value to getPage()

Comment: it will pass whatever's written by `out.write` -- I've edited my answer to show what I mean about the encoding, since you could have non-friendly characters in your request parameter that could corrupt the call to getPage.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to store it in a hidden field to access it from js. You can read it from the documents location. I personally use a method like this to grab GET parameters from my url.

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

var id = getUrlVars()['id'];

Comment: Thanks @Sir Troll your code is not giving error but when I passed getUrlVars()['id'] in my function getPage() its not executing getPage()