# How can I escape both quotation mark and backslash in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I need to escape " and \ in jsp, but not necessarily in the same time.

With `<c:out var="${value}" />` I can escape `"` character.

With `${fn:replace(value,'\\','&#92;')}` I can escape the `\` character, and is working fine.

I tried to handle both cases as follows.

I tried to use

```
<c:out var="${fn:replace(value,'\\','&#92;')}"/>
```

but is not working, is not accepted, seems to be an error.

I also tried to put in a `variable` the string after replace, and after that using it in `c:out`, but was the same thing.

If anyone has an idea of a way to handle both cases, please let me know.

Note: the input comes from `Java`, that's why I used `\\`, and is sent forward as `JSON`.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best solution to be [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) from `Apache`, and I had to create a taglib as @Tap said, and added jar file [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) to project . This has a lot of functions for working with strings.

More details can be found here [->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708242/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-from-within-a-jsp)

Answer (score 3):

You could call `fn:replace()` twice, chaining the calls, to replace both characters.

```
${fn:replace(fn:replace(value,'\\','&#92;'),'\"','&#34;')}
```

It's not very pretty, though.

Comment: Yes, is a good idea, but I need escaping other characters too with `c:out`. I don't know why to two don't work together.

Comment: Yeah, that could get ugly if you have lots of characters to replace.  So your objective is to have a proper JSON string?  You might want to do this outside of the jsp with a java library like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).  Or if the string is coming not from Java objects but from a back end, write a custom tag to do the exact formatting that you need.

Comment: Yep, I fixed at last. I used  `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`, which has methods for both escaping `HTML` and `Javascript`. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Good to know.  You should answer your own question to let others know how to solve the problem.