# JSP Request Parameter truncated after passing to javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have an issue with a parameter that I'm trying to pass into a Javascript function where the parameter gets cut off.

In my Servlet, I have set a parameter `request.setAttribute("questions", service.getQuestions("123"))`

It sets a list of questions with each question containing several values;

I loop through them with a JSTL loop `<c:forEach var="data" items="${questions}">...</c:forEach>` which I can then access the values as so `${data.question}, ${data.options}` etc.

`console.log(${data.question})` returns a value of the form `123,45,35|43,94,73|23,91,34` which is as expected.

But when I try to pass this `${data.question}` into a javascript function such as `<script>MyFunction(${data.question})</script>`, it only receives `123`.

```
MyFunction(data) {
    console.log(data); //Only shows 123
    //Split the string into arrays for processing
}
```

Comment: Beacause it returns the first element from the array

Comment: @sankrish It's a string, not an array.

Comment: `${data.question}` outside the `for-each` loop will hold the value for the current iteration alone

Comment: `${data.question}` is a string `123,45,35|43,94,73|23,91,34`, not an array.  The loop is to loop through the list `questions`.  `questions` contains several objects that have the attribute `question`, `options`, and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive first element becouse your function expect one parameter, and your value `123,45,35|43,94,73|23,91,34` is split by comma so it looks for function like diferent parametrs. Use **arguments** property insted or pass all **value as string in ''** like this

```
<script>MyFunction('${data.question}')</script>
```

Sorry for my english.. still working on it

Comment: I see, it was being passed as `MyFunction(123, 45, ...)` instead of `MyFunction("123,45,...")`

Comment: Don't forget to escape it! See [How to escape JavaScript in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708242/how-to-escape-javascript-in-jsp)
`<script>MyFunction('${util:escapeJS(data.question)}')</script>`