# Handling single quote in JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display values in a div of JSP dynamically. The below `$('#test${i}${j}')` selects a div dynamically as I want, but the HTML part is creating issue for me. `${column}` is just a value, for example, accountant, financeMR, etc.:

```
 <c:out value="<script>$('#test${i}${j}').html(${column});   </script>" escapeXml="false" />
```

In the above I get an error which says "accountant is undefined", etc. The reason being there is no single quote (') wrapping `${column}` (in HTML). However, if I try the below, it works in all cases except the cases where the `${column}` value contains a single quote. For example, Mng'r:

```
 <c:out value="<script>$('#test${i}${j}').html('${column}');   </script>" escapeXml="false" />
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: You have to use some JSP/Java function to escape all `'` inside `${column}`. There is nothing you can do on the client side, because the code won't even be executed if it contains syntax errors. If you can be sure that the value will never contain `"`, you can use double quotes for the string instead (but the correct approach would be to escape the delimiter).

Comment: ok in my jsp can i do something like  var abc=escape(${column});

Comment: is there a way i can do it in jsp itself? i mean i tried escape(${column}) doesn't work either.

Comment: As I said, you have to do that in JSP, but I'm not familiar with JSP. A quick search revealed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470768/how-to-escape-apostrophe-or-quotes-on-a-jsp-used-by-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708242/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-from-within-a-jsp

Comment: let me try it out..thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Apache commons lang library provides escape utilities: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

This should do the trick:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(inputString);
```