# Unescape entity references in HTML5 context.fillText()

Tags: html, jsp, canvas, jstl

I have a web application game where i have some text stored in a database. Java/JDBC is used to get the text from a database and store it in an Arraylist. The Arraylist is sent to the client where a JSTL forEach loop is used to convert the Arraylist into a Javascript array of strings using `<c:out value="eachString">`

During the game, i use a HTML canvas, and i print the value of these strings onto the canvas using `context.fillText().`

However, because `<c:out>` automatically escapes things, when the text is printed out - the following sort of sentence is printed:

`They couldn&#039;t do it`

instead of:

`they couldn't do it.`

So i was wondering is there some kind of function or easy method i could use which would take the text passed to the fillText method and translate all the entity references into their actual values.

Comment: Does it represent user-controlled data? If not, then just don't use `<c:out>`.

Comment: The problem is if i don't use <c:out>, the javascript array wont be created properly because semicolons, apostrophes etc won't be escaped out

Comment: The `<c:out>` is there not for. It's for escaping XML special characters, not for JS special characters. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9709168 how to properly escape JS in EL.