# how to escape quote in a variable sent by the server in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee

I am building a web application and i encountered an issue. My server sends a json variable to angularjs like this (ng-init attribute):

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init(${var})">
```

This variable contains quotes so i'd like to escape these quotes and then run the init function. Is there a proper way to do this ?

Comment: @BalusC, is the solution that you indicated easily adaptable to a non-JSF environment?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong duplicate link. This one is for JSP: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9708242

Comment: thanks that's very helpful.